# Retrieve a particular value of a Hasmap

Tags: jsf

First I store some **hashmap** in **session**:

```
Map<String, String> operadores = loadOperadores();

((HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
.getExternalContext().getRequest()).getSession()
.setAttribute("operadores", operadores);
```

Then, I am able to see that hashmap in some **view** with:

```
<h:outputText value="#{operadores}"/>
```

BUT, I am not able to retrieve a particular entry of that structure.

I have tried several expressions unsuccessfully.

```
<h:outputText value="#{operadores.someBean.someKey}"/>
<h:outputText value="#{operadores[someBean.someKey]}"/>
```

Could somebody give me any advice?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you see when you try that?

Comment: Just nothing at all.

Comment: I'm surprised that `#{operadores}` even works at all. Try `"#{sessionScope.operadores[someBean.someKey]}`

Comment: With #{sessionScope.operadores[someBean.someKey]} nothing appears. With #{sessionScope.operadores} the same as #{operadores}, the whole estructure.

Comment: UPS! sorry. There is a mistake in the data. This expresion work: 
<h:outputText value="#{operadores[someBean.someKey]}"/>

Comment: Well I also misspoke earlier: `#{operadores}` will work because in basic jsp,(I forgot) the container will search for an object in successive scopes until it finds it (or not). So everything is working as designed. You might want to use the more scope-specific syntax I recommended earlier however, to save the container the time it'll take to scan through multiple scopes before getting to the session scope. Your code will perform better for it

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll follow your advice.